# Get the similarity of two numbers with python

Tags: python

i'm studying about [Case-Based Reasoning algorithms](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~ian/CBR/cbr03.pdf), and I need to get the similarity of two numbers (integer or float).

For strings i'm using the `Levenshtein lib` and it handle well, but I don't know any Python lib to calculate the similarity of two numbers, there is one out there?
Anyone knows?
The result should be between 0 (different) and 1(perfect match), like `Levenshtein.ratio()`.

@update1:

Using Levenshtein.ratio we get the ratio of similarity of two strings, 0 means totaly different, 1 exact match, any between 0 and 1 is the coeficient of similarity.
Example:

```
>>> import Levenshtein
>>> Levenshtein.ratio("This is a test","This is a test with similarity")
0.6363636363636364
>>> Levenshtein.ratio("This is a test","This is another test")
0.8235294117647058
>>> Levenshtein.ratio("This is a test","This is a test")
1.0
>>>
```

I need something like that, but with numbers.
For example, 5 has n% of similarity with 6. The number 5.4 has n% of similarity with 5.8.
I don't know if my example is clear.

@update 2:

Let me put a real word example. Let's say i'm looking for similar versions of CentOS linux distributions on a range of 100 servers. The CentOS Linux version numbers are something like 5.6, 5.7, 6.5. So, how close the number 5.7 are of 6.5? It's not so close, we get many versions (numbers) between them. But there is a coeficient of similarity, let's say 40% (or 0.4) using some algorithm of similarity like Levenshtein.

@update 3: 
I got the answer for thia question. Im posting here to help more people:

```
>>> sum = 2.4 * 2.4
>>> sum2 = 7.5 * 7.5
>>> sum /math.sqrt(sum*sum2)
0.32
>>> sum = 7.4 * 7.4
>>> sum /math.sqrt(sum*sum2)
0.9866666666666666
>>> sum = 7.5 * 7.5
>>> sum /math.sqrt(sum*sum2)
1.0
```

Comment: `1 if a == b else 0`

Comment: Your question should not depend on outside links, as they can easily become broken. Also, it isn't clear what you mean by similarity. Perhaps some sample input and output would be helpful.

Comment: Ok,
let's get the example with strings: >>> import Levenshtein
>>> Levenshtein.ratio("This is a test","This is a test with similarity")
0.6363636363636364
>>>

Comment: Using Levenshtein.ratio we get the ratio of similarity of two strings, 0 means totaly different, 1 exact match, any between 0 and 1 is the coeficient of similarity.

Comment: @dogasantos You should edit any additional information into the question. Also, how the function works on strings doesn't give much guidance on how it should work for floats. What should `similarity(1.345, 1.354)` return?

Comment: Without knowing what rule you want to use, how do you expect anyone to help you code it? Just giving two examples that both say "n% of similarity" without telling us what `n` is in either case isn't even a _start_ on a definition. As written, anything would be a valid answer—even just `return 1.0`.

Comment: Specifying how close 5.7 and 6.5 are as floating point numbers without some idea of the scale seems pretty difficult. You could say they're, e.g., .877 similar because that's what `max(0, min(5.7/6.5, 6.5/5.7))`, but it sounds like you want them to be a lot less similar. (How much less similar? Surely 5.7 is a lot closer to 6.5 than 0 or -300 or 1e37, isn't it?) If you can give us a bunch of example of how close you want some different values to come to 6.5, someone can fit a curve to that, but without any clue at all, nobody can write anything.

Comment: After update 3: If that logic is what you want, you've already written it, so what's the question? If it's _not_ what you want, then what's wrong with it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you hope to accomplish, but arbitrary release numbers are arbitrary.

Comment: Hi, on the updste 3 i have the answer

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the easy, so simpel answer, truly genius.

Answer (score 5):

To calculate the similarity of 2 numbers (float or integer) I wrote a simple function

```
def num_sim(n1, n2):
  """ calculates a similarity score between 2 numbers """
  return 1 - abs(n1 - n2) / (n1 + n2)
```

It simply returns 1 if they are exactly equal. It will go to 0 as the values of numbers differ.

Answer (score 1):

From the link, I see that Ian Watson's slides show three options for assessing "similarity" of numbers.  Of these, the "step function" option is readily available from `numpy`:

```
In [1]: from numpy import allclose

In [2]: a = 0.3 + 1e-9

In [3]: a == 0.3
Out[3]: False

In [4]: allclose(a, 0.3)
Out[4]: True
```

To get numeric output, as required for similarity, we make one change:

```
In [5]: int(a == 0.3)
Out[5]: 0

In [6]: int(allclose(a, 0.3))
Out[6]: 1
```

If preferred, `float` can be used in place of `int`:

```
In [8]: float(a == 0.3)
Out[8]: 0.0

In [9]: float(allclose(a, 0.3))
Out[9]: 1.0
```

`allclose` takes optional arguments `rtol` and `atol` so that you can specify, respectively, the relative or absolute tolerance to be used. Full documentation on `allclose` is [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html).

Comment: Nice option @John1024, but it should return any number between 0 and 1. Its a requirement. But this could be useful!! Thanks!!

Comment: @dogasantos Good point.  I added versions that, for the step function case, produce numbers.

Comment: It's very close this, i'm testing with atol/rtol. Trying to get the desired behavior. Using only float/allclose is not the answer yet. Let me put a real word example. Let's say i'm looking for similar versions of CentOS linux distributions on a range of 100 servers. The version numbers are something like 5.6, 5.7 ... 6.5... N.N. So, how close the number 5.6 are of 6.5? It's not so close, but using for example float(allclose()) i can't get this result yet, because it only return 0 or 1, but should return something like 0.6.

Comment: "should return something like 0.6."  Using what test?  The step function test should only return 0 or 1.

Comment: This is why step function is not ideal for my case. I think cosine functions could be the path for this.